# How to find specific key in JSON which I decoded into PHP? The key I want to find is repeated on multiple level of nesting

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

> I want to target "KeyIwanttotarget" which is present on outside as well as nested.

The original file is JSON which I decoded into php using json_decode(). I want to target the specific key on all levels(external as well as nested) and store the value into another array e.g. using foreach and array_push.

```
"sample": [
    {
        "KeyIwanttotarget": "link",
        "abc": "123",
        "xyz": "123",
        "pqr": "123",
        "sample": [
            {
                "KeyIwanttotarget": "group",
                "abc": "123",
                "xyz": "123"
            },
            {
                "KeyIwanttotarget": "link",
                "abc": "123",
                "xyz": "123",
                "pqr": "123",
                "sample": [
                    {
                        "KeyIwanttotarget": "link",
                        "abc": "123",
                        "xyz": "123",
                        "pqr": "123", 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and please provide us with what your expected results should look like.

Comment: You need to make a recursive function that iterates through the array. Show us your attempt, the expected result and the result you're currently getting and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to recursively check all of your key values.  The best way to do that is with the `array_walk_recursive()` function.

This function allows you to use a callback function which will allow you to create some logic to compare your search string with the key names in the array to be searched.

The `array_walk_recursive()` passes two arguments through your callback function.  The key and the key's value.

You will pass those arguments in through the function. You will compare the key name against your search string and if it matches you will add the key's value to the results array.

Like so:

```
$results = array();

$searchString = 'KeyIwanttotarget';

array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key) use (&$results, $searchString) {

    if($key == $searchString){

        $results[] = $value;
        return $results;
    }

});

print_r($results);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad it helped you out.  Good luck with the rest of your project.  Cheers!